# wired white gap on mobile while zooming in or out

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-5

wired white gap on mobile while zooming in or out
It happens when I use background-color on sections
It only happens on mobile while zooming in it doesn't appear on the normal desktop I try a lot of fixes

[image]

Comment: Could be an issue with sub-pixel rendering. May be some clues here: https://medium.com/kajabi-ux/css-and-sub-pixel-rendering-the-case-of-the-clipped-border-4652c5a1b5ab

Comment: Please see [ask]. Code should not be presented as an image. Also take the [tour].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Borders on certain zoom levels on webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335633/borders-on-certain-zoom-levels-on-webpage)

Answer (score 0):

To address the white gap issue on mobile when zooming, first, ensure you have the viewport meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your HTML `<head>`. Check for CSS properties like `overflow` in your styles that may be causing the problem. Consider using relative units like percentages for element sizing, and thoroughly test your website on various mobile devices and browsers to confirm the issue's consistency.

Comment: yes i already do this i don't what else could i do