# How to remove weird gaps between three divs having the same background-color?

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with this issue for quite a while now. The issue can be seen on mobile devices (Android and iOS), some devices may need to be zoomed-in a little bit. On PC, I can also reproduce this bug on Chrome browser when switching to mobile mode. Below is the code using to reproduce the bug:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
    .top {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #553213;
    }
    .middle {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #553213;
    }
    .bottom {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #553213;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:300px; height: 300px">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The expected result would be a div which is fulfilled with #553213 color. However, on some mobile devices, they display additional lines (or gaps) between those three divs.

Om my iPhone

[image]

On my PC, using Chrome browser with mobile mode

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on here? Any ideas about how it happens and how to fix it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have margin 0? I can't reproduce, perhaps try setting the margin to -1px on each div.

Comment: It works!! Genius! But where are they come from? Btw, that solution unexpectedly broke other parts of my layout. Is there any other ways?

Comment: @MadisonCourto you can use any iPhone and open that page, some will display those gaps, some need to zoom-in a little bit. Android phones can also reproduce that issue as well. However, on my PC, I can't reproduce that bug. I think this bug is related with the way browsers on mobile phone render html, css.

Comment: Same here. Cannot reproduce on a PC. Probably a phone browser issue.

Comment: I wonder if the following applied to **.middle** and **.bottom** would help with the other parts breaking:

    `margin-top:-1px;`
    `height:101px;`

Sorry, I am also unable to see this issue on my devices to test it.

Comment: mobile browser issues probably

Comment: @NguyenYou how about margin-bottom: -1px for the top div, margin-top: -1px; for the bottom div, I assume you are saying the layout is broken due to the overall margins being reduced by not explicitly setting the margin to the top or bottom, only a guess as you didn't explain the issue.

Comment: It seems like this is an issue with certain browsers/operating systems/devices. This likely means that you can only 'fix' this by using a hack. Or suggest the developers of these browsers/operating systems/devices to fix the bug.

Comment: Could a box shadow solve this? 
Something like: `box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #553213;`

Comment: This issue reminds me of this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882283/pixelated-edge-around-a-css-circle-with-overflow-hidden 
Where a tiny white border was rendered around some css elements.

Comment: Since all these divs have the same background could you not just put the background colour on the parent element instead?

Comment: @NguyenYou check out my answer. I think is is just graphics problem which is producing at the specific scale of page.

Comment: Remove the doc type declaration. It's not part of the html5 spec.  There's a slim chance that you're forcing the render engine into an antiquated mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970787/space-gaps-between-divs-on-website-when-viewed-on-iphone-ipad/4334006) answer.

So the solution is to add a `margin-top: -1px;` to `top`, `middle`, and `bottom` classes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
    .top {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #553213;
    }
    .middle {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #553213;
    }
    .bottom {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #553213;
    }
    
    .top, .middle, .bottom {
      margin-top: -1px;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:300px; height: 300px;">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And it looks good on mobile and PC, too. The `div`s height doesn't change. It remains `300px`.

Answer (score 5):

I guess this is due to the scale of the page. Try to add this meta tag to the head:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">`

Answer (score 4):

After reading the comments I have seen that Madison Courto had a suggestion of

```
margin: -1px;
```

which was confirmed for solving the actual issue, but it has caused issues on other parts of the page. So, let's apply this idea for the actual divs only:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
    .top {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #553213;
    }
    .middle {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #553213;
    }
    .bottom {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #553213;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:300px; height: 300px">
    <div class="top" style="margin: -1px;"></div>
    <div class="middle" style="margin: -1px;"></div>
    <div class="bottom" style="margin: -1px;"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with `background`. This works fine in my mobile:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
    .top {
      height: 100px;
    }
    .middle {
      height: 100px;
      }
    .bottom {
      height: 100px;
      }
    div{
      background:#553213;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:300px; height: 300px">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what is actual cause. but when i tried below then color of white lines converted into black then i got this idea:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
    .top {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #553213;
    }
    .middle {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #553213;
    }
    .bottom {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #553213;
    }
    div:hover{background:#000;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:300px; height: 300px">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*click on top or bottom div*

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <style>
        .top,
        .middle,
        .bottom {
            min-height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #553213;
            margin-bottom: -6px;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 15px 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width:300px; height: 300px">
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="middle"></div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this issue might be due to the way `display` `block`, `inline-block` styles being handled by different browsers on different screens.

for example, `inline-block` elements will have an auto small space at right. 
people usally solve this using negative `margin-left`.

---

By default, a `div` is a `block` level element.

This bottom space you been facing could also be because of the way block level elements are being handled.

---

Like solving `inline-block` space with negative `margin-left`,

this `block` level space can either be solved using

- negative `margin-top` or
- changing `div`'s style to either `table`, `table-cell` type or `flexbox` type
  using css

Answer (score 1):

add a small outline to *hide* this issue:

```css
.container > * {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #553213;
  outline:1px solid #553213;
}

.container {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div  class="container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @NguyenYou even if you try 1px ?

Comment: Yup! However, I found something really interesting when increasing the outline-width to 35px. A bunch of weird gaps appear.

Answer (score 1):

Just try adding the margin-bottom to the top and middle divs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
    .top {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #553213;
   margin-bottom: -2px;
    }
    .middle {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #553213;
   margin-bottom: -2px;
    }
    .bottom {
      height: 100px;
      background-color: #553213;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:300px; height: 300px">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use display and margin bottom to fix styling.

```
.top, .middle, .bottom {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #553213;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use display and margin bottom to fix styling.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
  .top, .middle, .bottom {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #553213;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: block;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width:300px; height: 300px">
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```